# vtable size mismatch linking boost

Tags: c++11, boost, abi

A co-worker ran into a linker warning while linking something in Solaris:

```
ld: warning: symbol 'vtable for boost::system::error_category::std_category' has differing sizes:
        (file blah.o value=0x24; file (...)/libboost_system.a(error_code.o) value=0x14
        blah.o definition taken
```

... where the [apparently] offending code exists in boost/system/error_code.hpp.  This happens when compiled with `-std=c++11`, but not with `-std=c++98`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should've been obvious from the beginning but I was being dense.  We recently switched from C++98 to C++14, but the boost libraries were built with the compiler's default -- C++98.